# How to get html code from reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I need to send an email of my rendered reactjs component, for that, I need to convert my react component in HTML and send the email. I know how to send HTML through the mail, but getting stuck in how to get HTML from the reactjs component.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `renderToString` of `react-dom/server` and use it like

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)
```

`ReactDOMServer` is used for *SSR (Server Side Rendering)* of react components.

`renderToString` converts your React component to string. So, You will get string html from JSX of your component.

Comment: Tried to console htmlString but it shows only <div></div>, the complete component is not printed, so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It returns initial HTML only, If your component is re-rendering, It won't work.

Comment: My component is not re-rendering but if still, what should I use now?

Comment: I think I am getting only the parent component but not its child component.

Comment: Cant say without checking codes for your component.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that. One is the `renderToString()` method, as the other answer mentions.

The other one is `renderToStaticMarkup()`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

From docs:

> Similar to renderToString, except this doesn’t create extra DOM attributes that React uses internally, such as data-reactroot. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes can save some bytes.

> If you plan to use React on the client to make the markup interactive, do not use this method. Instead, use renderToString on the server and ReactDOM.hydrate() on the client.

For sending email you don't need extra DOM attributes or hydration since the email doesn't include any JS code, `renderToStaticMarkup()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To get HTML from a react component, you can use the`ReactDOMServer.renderToString` method ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)) used mainly for SSR purpose. However I guess you can achieve what you want with it.